# How to propagate gradients through torch.stack?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, concatenation

I'm trying to optimise a model using PyTorch. Below are two implementations of a minimum working example.

**Method 1** has a `torch.stack` call in it. The model does not train, and returns a constant loss:

```py
import torch

qx = torch.rand(100, dtype=torch.float32).requires_grad_()
qy = torch.rand(100, dtype=torch.float32).requires_grad_()
qz = torch.rand(100, dtype=torch.float32).requires_grad_()

x = torch.stack([qx, qy, qz]).T
y_true = torch.linspace(0, 10, 100)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([qx, qy, qz], lr=1e-2)

reporter_interval = 10
results = []
losses = []

for i in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.abs((y_true - (x**2).sum(1))).sum()
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer.step()

    if i % reporter_interval == 0:
        results.append(x.clone().detach().numpy())
        losses.append(float(loss))
        print(f'Iter {i}, loss: {float(loss)}')
```

**Method 2** omits the call to `torch.stack` and works directly on the 2d array. This model converges quickly to zero loss:

```py
import torch

qx = torch.rand(100, dtype=torch.float32).requires_grad_()
qy = torch.rand(100, dtype=torch.float32).requires_grad_()
qz = torch.rand(100, dtype=torch.float32).requires_grad_()

x = torch.stack([qx, qy, qz]).T
y_true = torch.linspace(0, 10, 100)

x = torch.tensor(x.detach().numpy(), dtype=torch.float32).requires_grad_()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([x], lr=1e-2)

reporter_interval = 10
results = []
losses = []

for i in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.abs((y_true - (x**2).sum(1))).sum()
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer.step()

    if i % reporter_interval == 0:
        results.append(x.clone().detach().numpy())
        losses.append(float(loss))
        print(f'Iter {i}, loss: {float(loss)}')
```

The only thing that changes between these two examples is what the optimiser operates on, i.e. either `[qx, qy, qz]` or `x`

What is it about `torch.stack` that prevents this from working, and is there an alternative? In my real model, I need to join data from multiple sources.

Thanks!

Comment: please make two separate "options" one with `stack` and the other without. It is not clear with all the comments what are the two alternatives

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: N.B. the same problems occur if I use `torch.cat` instead: `x = torch.cat([qx.reshape(100, 1), qy.reshape(100, 1), qz.reshape(100, 1)], dim=1)`

Comment: Your first method does not run: "RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation"

Comment: torch.stack doesn't point to references of its arguments, it creates copies of them. If you want x and loss to reflect the changes in qx, qy, and qz you need to reassign it every time you step the optimizer.

Comment: @shai works for me, might be a version issue - I'm on `1.4.0`

Comment: @jodag ahhh yes thanks! That makes sense ‍♂️. I will build the stacking into the loss function.